# Repeated Attempts to register accounts

Tags: users

I have a site with a many users, and public registration is not allowed, I'm the only one who can create accounts. I'm pretty new to drupal, and looking in the log messages I see this FREQUENTLY! What is this all about? Is someone trying to hack my site (sorry for the newb-termanology) but is this some sort of sqli or something I should be worried about? This happens often, and I'm wondering if my site has any vulnerabilities I should be worried about.

Thanks for helping shed some light on the situation!

page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm register'). Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm .url('user/register').  Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm register'). Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm .url('user/register').  Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm register'). Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm .url('user/register').  Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm register'). Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm .url('user/register').  Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm register'). Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm .url('user/register').  Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm register'). Anonymous
page not found  02/20/2013 - 2:56pm .url('user/register').

Comment: There is nothing to worry about. Since user/register is a well know path used by Drupal, somebody is trying to register, but they are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it "hacking", but someone (person or automated script) is definitely trying if you accidentally "left the door open". They found out that you didn't. Don't worry about it... As long as you keep your site up-to-date with security updates!